# Whats does new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(...)) return?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I'm curious to know what:

```
new ArrayList<Something>(
         Arrays.asList(
              new Something("1"),
              new Something("2")                                             
         )
);
```

returns?

Will it return an `ArrayList` containing those `Something` objects or will it return an `ArrayList` which contains a `List` of those `Something` objects (i.e `ArrayList<List<Something>>`)?

Comment: Why don't you try it, and see what comes out?

Comment: Maybe you should have look at the [JavaDocs for `ArrayList`'s constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Collection))

Comment: Why did you believe a `new ArrayList<Something>` could return an `ArrayList<List<Something>>`, when it specifically says that it's creating an `ArrayList<Something>`? The `new` operator cannot return something other than what is being *created*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will return the two Somethings in the list and not a list with the list, because the elements of the collection contained in the collection you add in the () will be added to the array list and not the collection as a collection.

Comment: Yes, but only with a language Level of 5+ you can leave those empty.

Answer (score -1):

It does not return anything, you're creating the instance of generic `ArrayList`.

the Arrays.asList ... here Arrays static method used to create the objects of Something class because the type of `ArrayList<>` hold Something class.

It's better to print the ArrayList to check what's come out.

```
for(Something something:myList){

    //print the objects here
}
```

Comment: In the creation of the list essentially a new Instance of the list is returned.

Comment: @Maxdola does constructor returns anything?

Comment: Yes essentially the Constructor returns a new instance of the object like when you write `return this;` in a method.